# loop through post categories and display custom field from each post wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have about 20 posts split into 4 categories.

Each post has got a custom field.

I want to loop through each category and display its name, then echo out the custom field for each post in the category.

Something like this:

```
Category name
    Post 1 custom_field
    Post 2 custom_field
Category name
    Post 3 custom_field
```

I have been searching around and cannot find out how to do this.

SO far i have got this code:

```
<?php
//for each category, show all posts
    $cat_args=array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $categories=get_categories($cat_args);

    foreach($categories as $category) {

        $args=array(
            'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
        );
        $posts = get_posts($args);

        if ($posts) {
            echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
            foreach($posts as $post) {
                $test = get_field('document');
                echo $test;
                setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                <?php
            } // foreach($posts
        } // if ($posts
    } // foreach($categories
    ?>
```

This will show something like:

```
Category name
    Post 1 title
Category Name 
    Post 2 title
```

But it does not show the custom_field.

If i do $file = get_field('document'); in the loop it doesnt work.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?